# How to set the system attribute of each folder that contains a desktop.ini?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, attributes, windows-10, desktop.ini

I use a software to backup my HDD to an other HDD. The sofware finds the differences first and mirrors them to the backup HDD then. Unfortunatelly, it ignores the folders' system attributes. This is a problem, because a lot of the folders have modified icons, that are displayed only if the folders' system attributes are set.

To correct this, I want to find all the affected folders. These are the ones that contain a desktop.ini file, so the system attributes should be set of such folders.

I know how to set the system attribute of a folder, but I don't know how to do it recursively, conditionally:

```
D:\>attrib +s ExampleDirectory
```

I guess I'll need a Windows batch script, but I'm not sure, as I don't know anything about batch programming.

Comment: Use the `robocopy` command to do your backups, it can copy both attributes and only the files that have changed.

Comment: `attrib` does not process folders unless you specify the `/D` option. I guess you want something like this: `for /D /R "D:\path\to\root\dir" %%D in ("*") do if exist "%%~D\Desktop.ini" attrib +S "%%~D" /D`. Anyway, perhaps you should witch to another backup tool that can handle all attributes correctly...

Comment: Agreed @Ross, the task should be to fix the backup routine, not try to patch up it's deficiencies.

Comment: @RossRidge Wow, `robocopy` is really useful, thanks. For most of my backups, this will be the way to go. In this certain backup task, I want to see all the differences before mirroring, so I think it'll be a 2 step proccess: use the usual backup software to compare, then use `robocopy` to mirror.

Comment: @aschipfl It looks like the code I was looking for. I'll try it, but I'm almost sure this will be the accepted answer soon. By the way `attrib` worked without `/D` in my example, but I accept it's needed in your example for some reason. Regarding your idea of switching my tool: I really love this product, so I think'll send them a bug report or a feature request.

Comment: `robocopy` has a "dry run" option `/L` which will show you everything it would do without actually doing anything.

Comment: I just realised that the `/D` option is only needed in case wild-cards like `?` and `*` are used, so it is not necessary in case a specific path is provided...

Comment: @Compo Good point. I'll ask the software developers to fix the backup tool, this will be the permanent solution. Until they fix it, I'll use `robocopy` to mirror. But right now, I'll use @aschipfl's solution to fix the last backup.

Comment: @RossRidge Really handy. The advantage of the software I use is the GUI: it shows all the differences using colors, folders can be collapsed/expanded easily, not to mention filtering and various comparison modes. So it's convenient when I backup this 1 TB, but `robocopy` still powerful.

Comment: I've contacted the developer of my current snyc software. Bad news: this is the intended behaviour. They had decided to mimic the behaviour of the OS. As my problem illustrates, Windows doesn't overwrite existing folders during a copy, only files. So the copy target folder attributes always remain the same, even if they should be updated to the copy source folder's attributes. Attributes are copied only if the folder doesn't exist at the copy target, i.e. it's a new folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to stick to your backup tool, which apparently cannot handle attributes correctly, you could use the following code based on [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)`/D /R` to reapply the `System` attribute for all directories that contain a file `Desktop.ini`:

```cmd
for /D /R "D:\path\to\root\dir" %%D in ("*") do (
    if exist "%%~D\Desktop.ini" (
        if not exist "%%~D\Desktop.ini\" (
            attrib +S "%%~D"
        )
    )
)
```

The two nested [`if`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) statements are required to apply the `System` attribute for directories that contain a file called `Desktop.ini`, but not for those that contain a directory of that name (although this might occur quite unlikely); the first `if` condition matches both files and directories, the second one does `not` match directories (note the trailing `\`).

Anyway, perhaps you should switch to another backup tool that can handle all attributes correctly, like [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), for example, which has been recommended by a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420091/how-to-set-the-system-attribute-of-each-folder-that-contains-a-desktop-ini#comment77801540_45420091).

---

The above approach does not handle hidden items correctly, because `for /D` does not recognise hidden directories, and `attrib` does not change the System attribute of hidden files. To overcome this, the code needs to be modified like this:

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('dir /B /S /A:D "D:\path\to\root\dir\*"') do (
    if exist "%%~D\Desktop.ini" (
        if not exist "%%~D\Desktop.ini\" (
            set "HIDDEN=%%~aD"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            if not "!HIDDEN!"=="!HIDDEN:h=!" (
                endlocal
                attrib -H "%%~D"
                attrib +H +S "%%~D"
            ) else (
                endlocal
                attrib +S "%%~D"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This makes use of the [`~a` modifier](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of the `for` variable reference and [sub-string replacement](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html).

Comment: Useful code and advices, thank you. Unfortunatelly this code ignores hidden directories.

Comment: This modification seems to help: `for /f "tokens=*" %%D in ('dir /a:d /b /s D:\path\to\root\dir') do (`

Comment: Even if the `for` is updated, the `attrib` still doesn't handle hidden directories, so these directories' hidden attribute should be removed first, and then both hidden and system attribute should be set at the same time. (Only if the hidden attribute was set initially.)